# Undefined variable error being thrown for function being returned

Tags: python, pylint

I have the following methods, is there something I am doing wrong or is this a false-error? I am getting an error on the line `return __initContract("AMD")`

```
@staticmethod
def __initContract(__symbol):
    contract = Contract()
    contract.symbol = __symbol
    contract.secType = "STK"
    contract.currency = "USD"
    contract.exchange = "SMART"
    return contract

@staticmethod
def AMD():
    return __initContract("AMD")
```

Comment: You would need to precede `__initContract` with the name of the class - it's not a globally-defined name.

Comment: @jasonharper thanks - that worked. If I lets say didn't have the `__` for `__initContract` would it still be the same case?

Comment: The double underscore doesn't matter in this case (it just discourages any code outside of the same class from accessing it).  Each class is its own namespace, anything defined inside is going to need some reference to that namespace in order to make any sense.